proper filename for the render output
I set this file name for the 'file output' node  (desk002fix.jpg) :

But got the unexpected result. Rather than getting the file , I got a folder with that name -> 'desk002fix.jpg' which contains file :

What is wrong ? How to set the proper name here ?

Does this answer your question? Blender Output Multiple Passes When Rendering with Specific Naming Scheme (2.8.2a)

The Base Path of the File Output node contains only the path without the filename. So whatever you enter there will be the path, if you enter a filename there you will get a subfolder with that name.
In the properties to the right you can rename the file. It will be named the same as the input which provides the image to be saved, always followed by the frame number, by default this is "Image" and a 4-digit number.
However, if you want your filename something different instead of Image0001.png, you can rename the input by double-clicking on it or entering the name in the File Subpath field below.
And if you do not want the frame number as 4 digits, you can enter # as placeholders for as many digits as you want, for example if you want a filename to be test_01.png for example, you can enter test_## (without extension, this is determined by the file format you choose) in the File Subpath field:

The exception to this rule is the OpenEXR MultiLayer file format. There you can use the naming conventions directly in the Base Path which is then changed to Path, because in this case the input names will be the names of the different layers in the EXR file (and it shows Layers now instead of File Subpath as well).
Here is a comparison between the two variants:

On the left:

File Format: PNG.
Base Path: C:\Output\png
File Subpath: two inputs, test_## and alpha_###

On the right:

File Format: OpenEXR MultiLayer.
Path: C:\Output\exr
Layers: two inputs, test_## and alpha_###

Now if you render frame 1, the left setting will create a folder png in C:\Output\ (if it does not already exist) and save two files there: alpha_001.png and test_01.png.
The right setting will save a file exr0001.exr (4 digits frame number since this is the default) directly in C:\Output\ and this EXR file will contain the layers alpha_### and test_## (notice that the layers will not carry the frame number, because otherwise rendering an animation will result in each file having different layer names.



Thanks for the detailed explanation. It answered why the multilayer exr has different behavior.

@andio Oh, and maybe I did not make that clear in my answer: the frame number placeholder # does not have to be at the end. So regarding your question you could use desktop###fix as File Subpath in case you wanted the frame number in there.
